# What would the criminal charge be?

Tags: theft

I have a very particular question for a figurative situation. In this scenario one has discovered that while shopping from a certain retailer online. That if you order same day delivery and you pay using a prepaid visa.That once you are connected to a shopper/driver you may add additional items to your order and will not be charged for them. Now this same person places additional orders with this technique. What if any would be the criminal charges?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question and you should ask a lawyer in your jurisdiction. Fraud and theft come to mind, in the US fraud over the internet may also attach Federal wire fraud and mail fraud charges.

Comment: Asking for a friend...

Comment: Fraud carries varying penalties based on nature/extent of the fraud and jurisdiction.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

**Theft**.

It doesn't matter who loses that money, and how it was possibly, if you take it while knowing it's not yours, it's theft, you are stealing.
If you could convincingly claim you didn't know you weren't charged, it's not stealing, but you still owe it back. But playing stupid is not a valid excuse.

Comment: compare https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theft with https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraud